# How can I configure VLANs with two servers?

Tags: cisco, vlan

I'm stuck configuring the following scheme, How do I make it to exist communication between every computer? It just communicate in PCs with the same VLAN(For example if I make ping between PC4 and PC5 the communication exist), except with PC6 that haves no communication with PC0 and PC1 and have the same VLAN.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide details such as the router and switch configurations, otherwise we can only speculate or guess, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

U should mention which switches have which interfaces set in which VLAN, if any.
However from your question it looks like few of your computers are in the same VLAN while few in are in different VLANS.
This is inter VLAN communication.
To enable this =, you need to make sure of a few things.
First you will need a layer 3 forwarding. This can be done using SVI or an actual router.
Secondly depending on your configuration you might want to set a few interfaces as trunk.
If you are using an SVI, the the default gateway of the PC should e the IP address of the SVI